# How to responsive menu bar without using any framework

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I am trying to design responsive menubar. This is the my html file.

```
<body>
  <div class="header">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="span_1_of_12">
           <a href="#" class="logoImage"/></a>
        </div>

        <div class="span_11_of_12">
          <nav class="navigation full-right">
             <ul class="menubar">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
             </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
  .container{
     width: 960px;
     position: relative;
     margin: auto;
 }

 .span_1_of_12 {
    width: 7.416%;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
    float: left;
 }

 .span_11_of_12 {
    width: 91.58%;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
    float: left;
 }
```

When I am trying to resize the browser window. menubar is cut @ right side of window. I attached the screenshot.

My assumption is menubar should should not be cut off at the right side of browser when resize the window to 800px. Because I mentioned width in the %age. it should adjust to available space. if it is wrong assumption. please suggest me right way.

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming the 6 home buttons are just placeholders for what will go there eventually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set your .container width to 100% or 100vw (viewport width). You can't have fixed width in pixels.

Comment: if i make container width 100% it will work but i want the body container should be 960px; and align to center of the browser

Comment: Set the max-width to 960px?

Comment: Working fine. please can you explain when should i use max-width?

Comment: Like you asked, if you want your web page to work a certain way until your reach your intended maximum size (in this case 960px). After that the web page should just stay at 960 px and add margins on both sides

Answer (score 0):

You could give your .container a 100% width and make another container inside, with width: 960px and margin: 0 auto

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for responsive menubar

```
   <body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="sticky">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="span_1_of_12">
                    <a href="#" class="logoImage"/></a>
                </div>

                <div class="span_11_of_12">
                    <div class="menuDisplayOnMobileButton">Menu<span     class="menuIcon"></span></div>
                    <nav class="navigation full-right">
                        <ul class="menubar">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mainBannerTextwrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="span_12_of_12">
                    <div class="mainBannerTextDiv">
                        <p>Vikram</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="aboutUsSectionContainer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="span_12_of_12">
                <div class="eachSectionHeading">
                    About US
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">

        </div>
    </div>
  </body>


JAVASCRIPT FILE 

     $(document).ready(function ()
     {
      $(window).scroll(function(){
       var sticky = $('.sticky'),
         scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= 100) 
                sticky.addClass('fixed');
           else
               sticky.removeClass('fixed');
      });



        $('.menuDisplayOnMobileButton').on('click', function()
         {
          $('.menubar').toggleClass('menubarMobile'); 
         }); 
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   responsive css file is

   .container{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 960px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

 .span_12_of_12 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
    float: left;
  }

  .span_11_of_12 {
    width: 91.58%;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
    float: left;
   }

  .span_10_of_12 {
    width: 83.16%;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
    float: left;
  }

 .span_9_of_12 {
     width: 74.75%;
     margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
     float: left;
   }

 .span_8_of_12 {
     width: 66.33%;
     margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
     float: left;
   }

 .span_7_of_12 {
       width: 57.91%;
       margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
       float: left;
  }

 .span_6_of_12 {
      width: 49.5%;
      margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
      float: left;
  }

  .span_5_of_12 {
      width: 41.08%;
      margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
      float: left;
  }

 .span_4_of_12 {
      width: 32.66%;
      margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
     float: left;
  }

 .span_3_of_12 {
    width: 24.25%;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
    float: left;
  } 

   .span_2_of_12 {
     width: 15.83%;
     float: left;
     margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
  }

  .span_1_of_12 {
    width: 7.416%;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
    float: left;
   }

     /*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

      .span_1_of_12, .span_2_of_12, .span_3_of_12, .span_4_of_12,  .span_5_of_12, .span_6_of_12, .span_7_of_12, .span_8_of_12, .span_9_of_12, .span_10_of_12, .span_11_of_12, .span_12_of_12 {
      width: 100%; 
      margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
     }

    .logoImage{
       margin: 0 auto;    
     }

    .menubar{
       display: none;
    }    

   .menubarMobile{
      display: block;
     }    

   .menuDisplayOnMobileButton{
      display: block !important;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      background: red;
      padding: 10px;
     }

   .menubar li, .menubar a{
       width: 100%;
       text-align: center;
    }

   .menubar li{
       border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
       background: rebeccapurple;
    }
  }

   .full-left {
      float: left;
    }

    .full-right {
      float: right;
    }

     .header{
       background: red;
       overflow: hidden;
     }

     .logoImage{
         display: block;
         height: 50px;
         width: 50px;
         background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat transparent;
      }

    .menubar li{
        float: left;
        display: inline;
      }

    .menubar li a{
       display: block;
       padding: 10px;
       text-decoration: none;
       color: #000;
       font-weight: bold;
     }

    .menuDisplayOnMobileButton{
          display: none;
     }

   .header{
           background: url(../images/banner.jpg) no-repeat transparent;
           max-width: 100%;
           height: 500px;
           background-size: cover;
           background-position: center;
     }

      .mainBannerTextwrapper{
         margin: 10% 25% 0% 25%;
         overflow: hidden;
       }

      .mainBannerTextDiv{
        border: 10px solid #fff;
       }

     .fixed {
        position: fixed;
        top:0; 
       left:0;
       width: 100%;
       background: red;
       z-index: 1;
     }

    .eachSectionHeading{
       text-align: center;
       font-size: 30px;
       margin: 4% 0;
    }
```